# Trying to subtract a std::chrono::duration from a time_point (C++), but my code isn't compiling. Any suggestions?

Tags: c++, time, duration, c++-chrono

I asked this question yesterday, but my thread got shut down, so I'm talking into the void. So, my code is not compiling, but I would very much like it to. Here's is my snippet:

```
float numSeconds = 50;
std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point startTime = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
auto duration = std::chrono::duration<float, std::chrono::seconds>(numSeconds);
startTime -= duration;
```

Seems like it should be pretty straightforward, but I'm getting an operator not found error when attempting the in-place subtraction. Any suggestions?  I've also tried replacing the third line with the following:

```
   auto duration = std::chrono::duration<float, std::ratio<1, 1>>(numSeconds);
```

However, that line doesn't seem to be the cause of the issues, both approaches seem valid. It's my final line still that is unhappy. The error code I am getting is:

```
"Error  C2679   binary '-=': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::chrono::duration<float,std::chrono::seconds>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)"
```

Additionally, when I change the last line to:

```
timer.m_startTime = timer.m_startTime - duration;
```

I get the following error code:

```
Error   C2679   binary '=': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock,std::chrono::duration<float,std::ratio<1,1000000000>>>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

Are these somehow incompatible types? I would think that they'd resolve to the same thing.

Comment: Don't know the full details. The duration you specify seems to have a different type than the default one of steady clock. There should be a type `std::chrono::steady_clock::duration`.

Comment: So it seems! However, `std::chrono::steady_clock::duration<float, std::ratio<1, 1>>` doesn't seem to be a valid way to initialize a duration, so I'm not sure how to get the correct duration type from a floating point number of seconds.

Comment: I think the problem is you trying to set/change the template arguments, which results is an incompatible type. But anyhow, I'm not really able to help you currently.

Comment: Possibly, I think I might've just needed an explicit cast. Trying `auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::steady_clock::duration>(
        std::chrono::duration<float, std::ratio<1, 1>>(seconds));` might be the ticket, since it compiles. I'll add this as an answer if it is actually doing the right thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
float numSeconds = 50;
```

The following line:

```
std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point startTime = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
```

could be more concisely written as:

```
auto startTime = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
```

Both syntaxes are equivalent and correct.

The reason this doesn't compile:

```
auto duration = std::chrono::duration<float, std::chrono::seconds>(numSeconds);
```

is that the second template argument to `duration` takes a `std::ratio`, not a `std::chrono::duration`.  The correct way to say this is:

```
auto duration = std::chrono::duration<float, std::ratio<1, 1>>(numSeconds);
```

The above means that `duration` has type `std::chrono::duration` with a *representation* of `float` and a *period* of <sup>1</sup>/<sub>1</sub> seconds.  That means that this is just a floating point count of seconds.

The second template parameter of `std::ratio` defaults to 1, so the above can be simplified to:

```
auto duration = std::chrono::duration<float, std::ratio<1>>(numSeconds);
```

And the second template parameter of `std::chrono::duration` defaults to `std::ratio<1>` so the above can be further simplified to:

```
auto duration = std::chrono::duration<float>(numSeconds);
```

The following doesn't compile:

```
startTime -= duration;
```

because `chrono` has a rule that says values with floating-point representation never implicitly convert to those with integral representation.  This is to avoid the truncating error that results when one assigns a `float` to an `int`.

There are several ways to fix this.  For example you could store the result in a `float`-based `time_point`:

```
auto anotherTime = startTime - duration;
```

`anotherTime` has type `std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock, std::chrono::duration<float, std::chrono::steady_clock::period>>`.

Or you could explicitly cast `duration` back to integral type:

```
startTime -= std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(duration);
```

If you choose the latter, then there really is no point in using `float` at all.  And the entire sequence could look like:

```
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
auto startTime = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
auto duration = 50s;
startTime -= duration;
```

or:

```
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
auto startTime = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
startTime -= 50s;
```

or:

```
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
auto startTime = std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - 50s;
```

Here is a 1h video tutorial on `<chrono>` that you may find helpful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P32hvk8b13M

Comment: Thanks Howard, this is incredibly thorough! I think that about covers every question I could have.